# VisualStudioCode как перенести панель ввода логина/пароля обратно в Терминал?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[image: Где располагаются панели сейчас]

Здравствуйте, раньше в редакторе VSCode запрос на ввод логина/пароля происходил внизу в терминале и ввод оставался там же. С некоторой версии ввод вынесли в отдельную панельку наверху. Для меня это не удобно, но способа вернуть как было я не нашел. Подскажите возможно ли это?

Comment: А вообще, для полноты картины, стоит добавить, что можно добавить в github свои ключи, и тогда пароль вводить будет не нужно. Очень помогает при активной работе с репозиториями. Если нужно более подробно - спросите меня в коммментариях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage(Шестеренка слева снизу) -> Settings -> Вводим в поиске: *git authentication* и убираем галочку с Github: Git Authentication. Далее нужно перезапустить VisualStudio.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]